# Google AdMod Native Ads with Recycler view

Tags: admob, android-recyclerview

I am writing Android App using recycler view with card view. 
I need to use Google AdMod Native Ads.

I tried searching for examples and google developer network also, but did not get a concrete solution.

Please help me with sample code or direct me to proper location where I can find this.

Answer (score 8):

Recently I stucked with the same question but I implemented AdMob native ads for the ListView. Then I decided to post my solution for that to [admobadapter](https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter). Hope it will help you. I suppose it's not very complex to customize my solution for RecyclerView/CardViews. BTW feel free to contribute/fork.

The **basic usage** could look like:

```
    ListView lvMessages;
    AdmobAdapterWrapper adapterWrapper;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initListViewItems();
    }

    /**
     * Inits an adapter with items, wrapping your adapter with a {@link AdmobAdapterWrapper} and setting the listview to this wrapper
     * FIRST OF ALL Please notice that the following code will work on a real devices but emulator!
     */
    private void initListViewItems() {
        lvMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);

        //creating your adapter, it could be a custom adapter as well
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        adapterWrapper = new AdmobAdapterWrapper(this);
        adapterWrapper.setAdapter(adapter); //wrapping your adapter with a AdmobAdapterWrapper.
        //here you can use the following string to set your custom layouts for a different types of native ads
        //adapterWrapper.setInstallAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);
        //adapterWrapper.setcontentAdsLayoutId(R.layout.your_installad_layout);

        //Sets the max count of ad blocks per dataset, by default it equals to 3 (according to the Admob's policies and rules)
        adapterWrapper.setLimitOfAds(3);

        //Sets the number of your data items between ad blocks, by default it equals to 10.
        //You should set it according to the Admob's policies and rules which says not to
        //display more than one ad block at the visible part of the screen,
        // so you should choose this parameter carefully and according to your item's height and screen resolution of a target devices
        adapterWrapper.setNoOfDataBetweenAds(10);

        //It's a test admob ID. Please replace it with a real one only when you will be ready to deploy your product to the Release!
        //Otherwise your Admob account could be banned
        //String admobUnitId = getResources().getString(R.string.banner_admob_unit_id);
        //adapterWrapper.setAdmobReleaseUnitId(admobUnitId);

        lvMessages.setAdapter(adapterWrapper); // setting an AdmobAdapterWrapper to a ListView

        //preparing the collection of data
        final String sItem = "item #";
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(100);
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            lst.add(sItem.concat(Integer.toString(i)));

        //adding a collection of data to your adapter and rising the data set changed event
        adapter.addAll(lst);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And the **result** will look like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/master/screenshots/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif)

**UPDATE: Integration**

You can simply copy the following sources from github

```
admobadapter/admobadapter/src/main/java/com/clockbyte/admobadapter/AdmobAdapterWrapper.java
admobadapter/admobadapter/src/main/java/com/clockbyte/admobadapter/AdmobFetcher.java
```

to your `java` sources folder (feel free to edit the package names in all files but please leave the License header as is).

and the following resources

```
admobadapter/admobadapter/src/main/res/layout/adcontentlistview_item.xml
admobadapter/admobadapter/src/main/res/layout/adinstalllistview_item.xml
```

to your `res/layout` folder. Also please don't forget to copy the `string` resource `test_admob_unit_id` from `admobadapter/admobadapter/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` to your `strings.xml` file.

**After** implementation all the steps you'll have to change the declaration of the `AdmobAdapterWrapper` at least like this:

```
public class AdmobAdapterWrapper extends RecyclerView.Adapter<your ContactViewHolder class> implements AdmobFetcher.AdmobListener {

//...
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<your ContactViewHolder class> mAdapter;

    public RecyclerView.Adapter<your ContactViewHolder class> getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter<your ContactViewHolder class> adapter) {
//...
}
```

then I guess you'll have to replace some of the `AdmobAdapterWrapper's` methods  by `RecyclerView.Adapter's` specific methods, I suppose that it will be enough to replace the `getView(...)` by `onBindViewHolder(...)` and `onCreateViewHolder(...)` so seems this part of job is up to you :) It doesn't seem very hard. Then you can simply use it with your `RecyclerView` like in the example above :

```
AdmobAdapterWrapper adapterWrapper = new AdmobAdapterWrapper(this); 
  adapterWrapper.setAdapter(your_recyclerview_adapter_that_will_be_filled_with_your_data); 
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterWrapper);
```

If you'll extend `AdmobAdapterWrapper` for  the `RecyclerView.Adapter` please don't hesitate to contribute/fork to my lib. It will be very appreciated!
I'm going to extend the `RecyclerView.Adapter` wrapper for my lib a bit later but I have no time for it at the moment, sorry...**Is there any possibility for you to use a ListView instead of RecyclerView for some time?** However if you'll have a questions please don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking mainly for recycler view without using another SDK as wrapper .

Comment: No problem. BTW There's no any "SDK" or something like that, There's only an Adapter (AdmobAdapterWrapper) which you can get and use with your RecyclerView (need to be a little bit customized).

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find this wrapper ? I am not able to import this class - "AdmobAdapterWrapper". Please help me in this.

Comment: @ThonteshRenukarya What exactly was the problem? Please take a look to the UPDATE section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve this in without any wrappers only. If someone needs, I can give the code.

Comment: @ThonteshRenukarya so why you asking this question then if you could solve it yourself :)

Comment: Well, I could resolve after spending lot of time. I thought if somebody tried this new native ad from Google could help.

Comment: @ThonteshRenukarya Hi again! BTW I have implemented a support for a RecyclerView in my lib, so you could take a look. Welcome!

Comment: I tried your library and it works. But how can I set the position of the first ads item? It always equals number of item between ads.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh Hi! I'm going to implement it soon

Comment: Great news. Love to have this improvement

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh it was just implemented to the **first_adv_index branch** (experimental)

Comment: Hi used your adapter for RecyclerView, and its work fine. But on the click event i am getting the position with the AD so i cant get the correct item from the array. If the add is displayed as 3rd item and while i click 4th item i am getting the position as 4 whiles its the 3rd item in the array. How to solve it.

Comment: @binuj Hi, kindly take a look at the answer on the 2nd issue described here https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/issues/10 . Is it the thing you are looking for? Please just edit that snippet for RecyclerView.

Comment: Thanks its fixed the problem.

Comment: @kot331107 Hello, I really like your library and would like to use it for my RecyclerView. However, the `notifyItem*(int position, ...)` methods don't work correctly. If for example an AdMob ad is located at position 2, and I "refresh/change" the item at position 5, then it refreshes position 4 instead. I think something goes wrong at the translation of the position. Could you look into this, please?

Comment: @ThomasVos thx, pls take a look https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/issues/85